# Angular Velocity of Astronomical Bodies If Earth Was the Center of the Universe

Tags: orbital-motion, simulations, solar-system

I'm working on a simulation of the solar system. The simulation doesn't need to be physically accurate. It only needs to look *right* from the viewpoint of a simulated observatory at an arbitrary point on Earth.

For the purposes of this simulation, it'd be far cheaper (computationally) if I could keep Earth stationery. Therefore, rather than having the Earth orbit the sun, I was hoping to take the Sun around the earth. Figuring out the (average) angular velocity, in this case, is rather easy. 360 degrees in 24 hours or $7 \times 10^{-5}$ radians per second.

However, I'm not so sure how the other planets fit into this model. Can I somehow calculate an orbit and angular speed for the planets w.r.t. our stationary earth? Or should the planets simply orbit our *earth-orbiting* sun? Would that look right?

Answer (score 1):

The outer planets (Mars etc) all exhibit [retrograde motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrograde_and_prograde_motion), when they apparently move 'backwards' as seen from Earth for a part of their orbit.

When astronomers shifted from the geocentric model to the heliocentric, it certainly did not make their calculations more difficult: on the contrary they were simplified. All you have to do is to translate the heliocentric position of a planet, by the heliocentric position of Earth, to get its geocentric location.

If you want to obtain the apparent angular velocity, calculate two geocentric positions from the above, at different times, and calculate the AV from the difference. But you probably don't need the apparent angular velocity anyway, only the relative position.

Alternatively, use a lookup table to obtain approximate planetary locations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your comment regarding the complexity of the math is certainly true in a normal scenario. However, I'm creating this simulation inside a game engine, and the game engine has a few certain limitations. The best way to deal with them, is to have the observatory be a fixed unmoving point in the universe. That's why I'm looking for a model that fixes earth in place.

Comment: There's readily available planetarium software that does precisely what you're asking about. "Stellarium" for example.

Comment: @D.Halsey perhaps OP *wants* to make one. You can buy many things ready-made.

Comment: @MohammedFarahmand my point is that there isn't a computationally simple formula for apparent geocentric motion. The simplest way is to use circular solar orbits and translate to the Earth as centre. It doesn't get much simpler than that, computationally. But another way you can approach it is to make a lookup table. That's what an ephemeris is, and perhps a simple one is good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are correct on both accounts. The latter point is why I was hoping the suggestion in the last paragraph would work; to have the sun (and the moon) orbit the Earth while every other planetary object orbits the sun according to the heliocentric model. I was hoping if anyone could confirm that this would look *right* before I start working on it.

Comment: You *can't*, because the outer planets do not orbit Earth in a regular way. They move forwards, backwards, at varying rates.

Comment: @WeatherVane  I'll look into ephemeris. Should be simple enough to generate in Python and read that data. Thank you for your help.